# How to describe in flow removing props in react HOC

Tags: flowtype

I’ve looked at several articles about how use flow with hoc, but didn’t get what to do if I don’t want to pass all props.

```
/* @flow */
import * as React from 'react';

type TComponent = {
  pass: string,
  inject: string
}
const TestComponent = ({pass, inject}: TComponent) => <span>{pass}{inject}</span>

type THocDiff = {
  take: string
}

const Hoc = (Component) => class Hoc extends React.Component {

  render(){
    const {take, ...props} = this.props
    return(
        <Component {...props} inject="inject"/>
    )
  }
}

const WrappedComponent = Hoc(TestComponent)

const Using = () => (<WrappedComponent pass='pass' take='take'/>)
```

[try](https://flow.org/try/#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)

I would like to describe only diff props in the `HOC`:
don’t describe the `HOC’s` props in a wrapped component and don’t describe wrapped component props in the `hoc` either.

Comment: you pass `take` but no `take` in `TComponent`, it's confusing

Comment: because I use it only in hoc, I don't need it in props of TestComponent this is the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use: [Generics](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/), [$Diff](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-diff) and [Hoc definition](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/#toc-the-trivial-hoc):

```
import * as React from 'react';

type TComponent = {
  pass: string,
  inject: string
}
const TestComponent = ({pass, inject}: TComponent) => <span>{pass}{inject}</span>

type THocDiff = {
  take: string
}

type TInjectInHoc = {
  inject: string
};

const Hoc = <T: {}>(Component: React.AbstractComponent<T>): React.AbstractComponent<$Diff<T, TInjectInHoc> & THocDiff> => {
  return class extends React.Component<T & THocDiff> {

  render(){
    const { take, ...props} = this.props;
    return(
        <Component {...props} inject="inject" />
    )
  }
 }
}
const WrappedComponent = Hoc<TComponent>(TestComponent)

const using = () => (<WrappedComponent pass="123" take='take' />)
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amAAqAYRa4AdtRlEAvGADeqMGGzkyALjBkCedDIDmAGnVhjAK2oM9Bo6dQBfVHTgyD46gak5PeSUwAAoVLTIyMysZWwYXPUlpQIUASjBFAD4wAB4yLRlM8O0XFRs7Ahcc4HySQv4hEXEACTg6ABF0KCgM1UsCEgBragdDYxNXBuFRMQBJWIr51rpetQ1y+30x5xc+d09vZd6csT0VF0yQ-1kgvRp6AgA6AEEAI0cH65SCE8zUu64TzeHwYXzkChyABJOt0TtE5gsGEs2tkAGQtNowqDZLJ9DScAgAVzwMjAdBg2jA1AAHgR5AATCj3BiPMFBE5gdFiZZY7JrMCWTgyenUPAhVL8jQeLxEFRgAbDaKPZXYZjYMguXoEAAW6DIj1VcHVfA0+OoRJJIUspo0AEgcmyFKplQa1RqYnECIoAEQbAjesDATLWsCpSxuMBuNz8aXeADqeBI2BE9MdwWWJzTlzEvgIabDMYOREJZHGvXFGWyIRyCaTKbTmm0PoAjAAmADMAYV1EUbG7bEDfyAA)

Comment: But HOC, doesn't know what is in TProps.. I've add try, maybe it could help to understand my task.

Comment: @KherelKetchil so your question is not about how to remove item from object, but about how to describe hoc in general?